# Is there any difference between assert.GreaterOrEqual and Assert.IsTrue in nUnit?

Tags: nunit, assert

I am making asserts in one test and I want to test in the number of messages sent is >=1

I have two equivalent ways to do it.

```
        1: Assert.IsTrue(messagesSent >= 1);
        2: Assert.GreaterOrEqual(messagesSent,1);
```

**Is there any difference between first and second way of asserting?** I was wondering something inside nUnit or in the output errors or performance.. Or the only reason is readability?

If there is no difference, why the second has been created?

**NOTE**: Same apply for similar asserts like Greater, Less, LessOrEqual...

**NOTE**: I am going probably to use second one because I guess that if it has been created there is a good reason for it, but wanted to know why.

Comment: The 2nd form should yield a more useful message and, some might say, shows the intent of the test better.

Comment: So the only reason seems is readability and output message....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is different for failures.  For IsTrue, the message will be something like "Expected true but was false."  For GreaterOrEqual, the message will be something like "Expected 1 or greater, but was -15."  GreaterOrEqual provides more info in that you will see the actual value, which is more useful when debugging failures.